# How to create an reusable element similar to Selenium extend elements in Cypress.io?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

In Selenium, it's possible to extend elements. This makes it possible to have a set of reusable custom elements for testing.

For example, we can have a `getText` method added.

```
public static string GetText(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text;
}
```

And re-use it as follows:

`myElement.getText();`

This example is detailed here: http://www.vcskicks.com/selenium-extensions.php

Is there a way to replicate this behavior in Cypress.io? Or do we need to query and call the same methods to get the data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this using simple functions. For example, you could move several functions into a `utils.js`.

```
export const getByText = (text) => cy.contains(text)
```

And then import those methods into your spec file.

```
import { getByText } from './utils'

it('finds the element', () => {
  getByText('Jane Lane')
})
```

You could alternatively create a [custom command](https://on.cypress.io/custom-commands#Best-Practices), but that's sometimes not necessary as noted in the [best practices](https://on.cypress.io/custom-commands#Best-Practices).

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Custom Commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) is what you're looking for.  However, note the Cypress [Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices).  The basic commands are very powerful and you can accomplish a lot with them.